# How remove password from response in django

Tags: python, django, rest

Code:
SERILIZERS

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("email", "user_name", "password")

def create(self, validated_data):
    return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

VIEWS

```
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def CreateUserView(request):
    serializer = RegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
       user = serializer.save()
       if user:
          return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

MODELS

```
class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, user_name, password, **other_fields):

    if not email:
        raise ValueError(_("You must provide an email address"))
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, user_name=user_name, **other_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user
```

After i post user i got response data with password.

```
{
"email": "mawqgvxdfdat1@mat.com",
"user_name": "sdwxcvgfsdefsdf",
"password": "pbkdf2_sha256$320000$g74DLAMRDypcK6LuGriBio$
}
```

How can i remove that password from returned data?

Comment: Why did you remove the correct tick from my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments), you can use extra_kwargs. So your serializer would look like -

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email", "user_name", "password")
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Into serializer

```
fields = ("email", "user_name",)
extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

Actually delete password field from it